# Submit button disabled until another button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a website for a company to book a holiday for the employees. When you put the dates in I have a check button and a submit button. I want the submit button to be disabled until the check button is clicked but I cant figure out how to do it. Any ideas?

These are my form buttons

```html
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<input type="button" id="check" name="check"><label for="check">Check</label>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" disabled >
```

And this is what I have so far but it does not work...

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var button = $("input[type='button']"),
  submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");
  button.click(function () {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !button.is(":clicked"));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What have you done so far? It is very simple. In the onclick event of the checkbox set the this.form.submitbutton.disabled=!this.checked

Comment: What else does the check button do?  You've tagged this as Classic ASP. Classic ASP is server side code, which means that it runs when the page loads, so you would need to submit a form to get it to do anything.  Your check button would need to be a form of its own.  If this is a job for JavaScript then maybe you need to add that tag

Comment: It is in a form. And it is not a check box sorry, it is a submit button but i am using it to check the holidays to see if they are available or unavailable

Comment: What does check actually do? If it does a postback then you need to check the result

Comment: @Lankymart I have updated my question so it now contains some code

Comment: @mplungjan I think he just wants to toggle the disabled based on whether he click the button with id `check` is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You cannot check "checked" on an input that is not a radio or a checkbox

[<kbd>**Live Demo code**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7A5R4/)
[<kbd>**Live Demo for IE**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7A5R4/show)

```
$(function() {
  var button = $("#check"),
  submitButt = $("#submit");
  button.on("click",function(e) {
     submitButt.prop("disabled",false); // NOT a toggle
  });
});
```

This label does not make sense either unless you change the input to a checkbox

It should be

```
<input type="button" id="check" name="check" value="Check" />
```

If you had a checkbox, as it seems you might have had before, the code is

```
$(function() {
  var chkbox = $("#check"),
  submitButt = $("#submit");
  chkbox.on("click",function(e) {
     submitButt.prop("disabled",!this.checked); // Toggle
  });
});
```

using

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check">
<label for="check">Check</label>
```

Comment: The submit button is not showing when using Internet Explorer. Any ideas why?

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7A5R4/) - it sounds like you missed an end bracket - try [this in IE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7A5R4/show/)